# Unknown date format /Date(1427982649000-0400)/

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to display on the screen some date values but I'm receiving them in a format that I don't know. Does anybody know what format is this and how to convert them?

For example, I'm getting this:

```
/Date(1427982649000-0400)/
```

In the database is stored as

```
2015-04-02 09:50:49.000
```

I really don't know where to start looking at.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a unix timestamp in milliseconds, followed by a timezone (shift in hours differing from UTC).

So, it's UTC -4 hours, 1427982649 seconds after the 1st January of 1970.

Nice little tool for checking unix timestamps : http://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php (don't forget to convert your milliseconds to seconds before posting them there)

/edit: To add some additional information - the "timezone shift" seems to be following [RFC822](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc822.txt) (and/or probably some other RFCs), that -0400 can be explained by the syntax "+/-HHMM" specified there, so to be exact it means -04 hours, 00 minutes.

Comment: The offset may or may not follow the standard convention, there is nothing in the OP to indicate either way. The ECMAScript convetion is opposite to that used by ISO 8601 *et al*. If the common convention is used (positive for east) then the missing timezone in the example "2015-04-02 09:50:49.000" could -0800. If the ECMAScript sense is used, it could be UTC (i.e. +0000).

Comment: I assumed the database timestamp to be displayed in the OPs local timezone (like most database tools do, IIRC) - if it isn't you are right, some additional checks by the OP are needed. Given the available facts I consider it being like I explained to be the "best guess", but I can't guarantee it to be correct with the facts that are given.

Answer (score 4):

The actual time and date gets converted into the milliseconds, and it follows the Unix time January 1st, 1970. 
Because it is the date when the time for the Unix computer started.

But you can convert the milliseconds into the actual time by using some loops or conversions according to that time.

Answer (score 2):

> Does anybody know what format is this and how to convert them?

It seems that "/Date(1427982649000-0400)/" is a time value in milliseconds followed by an offset as ±HHmm. To convert that to a Date, use the time value adjusted by the offset.

Assuming the offset uses the typical sign convention, then a positive offset needs to be subtracted and negative offset added to get the correct UTC value, then something like the following should suit:

```js
var s = '/Date(1427982649000-0400)/';

// Get the number parts
var b = s.match(/\d+/g);

// Get the sign of the offset
var sign = /-/.test(s)? -1 : +1;

// Adjust the time value by the offset converted to milliseconds
// and use to create a Date
var ms = +b[0] + sign * (b[1].slice(0,2)*3.6e6 + b[1].slice(-2)*6e4);

console.log(new Date(ms).toISOString()); // 2015-04-02T17:50:49.000Z
```

In your example, "2015-04-02 09:50:49.000" does not have a timezone, so it represents a different moment in time for each timezone with a different offset. If that is the actual value stored in the database, then I guess the missing timezone is UTC-0800. It is much better to store the values using UTC and to include the offset, then the host timezone is irrelevant.

Things are complicated here because ECMAScript timezone offsets are the opposite sign to the normal convention, i.e. positive for west of Greenwich and negative for east. If that convention is applied, then "/Date(1427982649000-0400)/" converts to 2015-04-02T09:50:49.000Z, which may be what you're after.

If that is the case, just change the sign in the line:

```
var sign = /-/.test(s)? -1 : +1;
```

to

```
var sign = /-/.test(s)? +1 : -1;
```

Comment: Genious!:))))))